# html5 video load() gets InvalidStateError

Tags: jquery, html, video, load, html5-video

I'm trying to load change the `currentTime` of a HTML5 video Player, capture an Image and go back to the old position in the video.

It works If I ad a `alert();`, but it's not working without. Therefore I tried to call `video.load()`, but this gives me this Error message:

`Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.`

This is my code:

```
function myHandler(e) {
    a = $('#testvideo').get(0).currentTime;
    generateThumbnail(a);
}

function generateThumbnail(i) {
    var video = $('#testvideo').get(0);
    for(var j =0; j<4;j++){
        video.currentTime = i+ (j/2);
        if(video.readyState!=4){
            video.load();
            video.addEventListener('loadeddate', function() {
               console.log(video.readyState);
                generateImage(i,j);
            }, false);
        }else{
            generateImage(i,j);
        }
    }
    returnToPause(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to tell from your code snippet, but you are probably trying to set the currentTime before your video has loaded. Try running your code after the loadedmetadata event has been thrown:

```
$('#testvideo').on('loadedmetadata',function(){
    // do what you want with this.currentTime
})
```

Answer (score 0):

So IO solved it this is my solution if someone else needs it again.

I just use the eventlistener `seeked` tho handle that the currentTime has changed and the video has loaded.

```
video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function(){
    video.currentTime = startTime;
});

//if video is ready to play grab the images
video.addEventListener('seeked', function(){
    generateImage();
});

if(frameTime <= snippetLength * framesPerSecond){
    var canvas = $('#canvas').get(0);

    imageArray[frameTime] = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    ....
    frameTime++;
    video.currentTime = +startTime + frameTime/framesPerSecond;
}else{
    displayCurrentImages();
    displayCurrentTime();
}

function returnToPause(i){
    var video = $('#testvideo').get(0);
    video.currentTime = i;
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: I had a similar error. This code would trigger the error and no other browser (not even Edge) had this problem:

`video.src = 'some URL'; video.currentTime = 0;`

Fixing it was to add 'load' event handler and set the value then.

Answer (score 0):

video.currentTime =xxx; can be set on Listener play

Exp.

```
video = document.getElementById('video');
begin_play  = 50;
play_video_frist = true; //if you want to run only frist time    
video.addEventListener("play", capture, false);

function capture(event) 
{
     if (event.type == "play"){
         if(play_video_frist){
             play_video_frist = false;
             video.currentTime = begin_play;
          }
     }
}
```